# What is the difference between Cholestanol 5alpha and 5beta?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

What is the isomeric relation between 5Alpha Cholestanol and 5Beta Cholestanol. I know that those forms appear after Hydrogenation of Cholesterol but unfortunately I cannot find any article or structural molecule of those, I think isomers, in internet, so if anyone can share a structural molecule, show the reaction mechanism or at least tell the isomeric relation I will be very thankful.

N.B: I assume that there is some kind of cis/trans isomerism but don't know exactly where it is. Am I right about that?

Comment: When cholesterol is drawn in the traditional way having ring A on the left and ring D on the right, hydrogenation of the 5,6-double bond from the top side produces C5-beta-cholestanol while hydrogenation form the bottom side affords C5-alpha-cholestanol. Beta is cis; alpha trans A/B-ring juncture. Mnemonic: top:bottom::beta:alpha. Words with more letters go together.

Comment: Ahha, ok thanks man, that was super helpful. I appreciate your answer:)

Comment: As someone who is new to ChemSE, you might want to familiarize yourself with some aspects of [Comments](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Nikimiskata if you got your answer, feel free to self answer it. Self answer are always appreciated and it also help future readers.